# first key of map is dissapeared

Tags: visualforce, map, csv

CSV File contains headers. Full Name - is first column header, Manager Email - last column header.

after file input, i create map that contains 
rowIndex (for VF apex:repeat), 'Header'='Value' (Map)

If  I try to display Full Name (first header) or Manager Email (last header) on VF-page:

> Map key Full Name not found in map
>
> Error is in expression '{!values[n]['Full Name']}' in component  in page ruit_ios_app

But if i delete this expression from page, it works.

**APEX CONTROLLER**

```
public void importCSVFile() {
        try {
                csvAsString = csvFileBody.toString();
                csvFileLines = csvAsString.split('\n');
                List<String> headers = csvFileLines[0].split(';');

                for (Integer i = 1; i < csvFileLines.size(); i++) {
                    List<String> csvRecordData = csvFileLines[i].split(';');

                    Map<String, String> newMap = new Map<String, String>();
                    for (Integer j = 0; j < headers.size(); j++) {
                        newMap.put(headers[j], csvRecordData[j]);
                    }
                    numbers.add(i);
                    values.put(i, newMap);
                }
```

**PAGE**

```
 <apex:repeat value="{!numbers}" var="n">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{!values[n]['Full Name']}</td>
                                    <td>{!values[n]['Email']}</td>
                                    <td>{!values[n]['Last Check In']}</td>
                                    <td>{!values[n]['OS Version']}</td>
                                    <td>{!values[n]['Device Model']}</td>
                                    <td>{!values[n]['Country']}</td>
                                    <!--<td>{!values[n]['Manager Email']}</td>-->
                                </tr>
                            </apex:repeat>
```

Comment: You should not assume any specific ordering in the keyset. Sets have no ordering.

Comment: hi Phil! Which ordering do you mean? do you mean  when i said "first column"?

Comment: You edited the question and removed the assumption you could get the 0th entry from the keyset as a list. This was what I was talking about at the time

Comment: a bit unusual for csv columns to be delimited by semi-colon rather than comma

Comment: it's csv generated from excel, i don't know why it generates like that))

Answer (score 0):

That it is only occurring for a subset of the columns makes me think that your input CSV might not contain the exact headers `Full Name` and `Manager Email`.

It is possible that there are encoding issues with those headers. E.g. In reality they might actually be `"Full Name"`, or `Full Name` (with a trailing space), or any other combination of characters that would be possible in a CSV. Especially if it was encoded poorly.

At a minimum, I'd suggest starting with assertions to ensure the expected headers are present.

```
List<String> headers = csvFileLines[0].split(';');
System.assert(headers.contains('Full Name'));
System.assert(headers.contains('Email'));
System.assert(headers.contains('Manager Email'));
```

In reality you would do better error handling here when the input CSV doesn't meet the expected format, but it will do to at least get things going.

---

You could also assert that the expected values are in the resulting map.

```
Map<String, String> newMap = new Map<String, String>();
for (Integer j = 0; j < headers.size(); j++) {
    newMap.put(headers[j], csvRecordData[j]);
}
System.assert(newMap.containsKey('Full Name'));
System.assertNotEquals(null, newMap['Full Name']);
// Repeat assertions for other problem keys

numbers.add(i);
//...
```

Comment: Hello Daniel! Thank you really for you reply. But the reason is these headers are first and last. If i move Full Name column to 2nd position and manager Email to 2nd from the end - i can display them on vf page.

Comment: @IvanS. In that case I'd expand that assertions being made in the code to include the records going into `newMap`. The objective is to narrow down where the problem is occurring.